# how to avoid re initialization of session value after redirecting to same page

Tags: c#

I have intialized some session variables in `page load` method to zero. Then I am modifying them in `button press` method. I am using one session variable as a counter but when I am redirecting the page to the same page, the variables are intialized again. Please help me to prevent this re-initialization. *I don't want to use static variables*.

The scenario is-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    session["counter"] = 0;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = (int)session["counter"];
    count++;
    session["counter"] = count;
    response.redirect("same page");
}
```

Comment: You should use a postback validation, `if (!Page.IsPostback)`, but why are you using a `session variable` if you're only using it in the same page? use a `viewstate variable` instead, or even a normal `property` for the `class`. Also the answer from dougajmcdonald will perfectly work for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want to check for a non set session variable and if so, set it to zero, then you could just do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if(session["counter"] == null) {
          session["counter"] = 0;
      }
 }
```

There are also a range of client side options you could use, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
    session["counter"]=0;
 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count=(int)session["counter"];
    count++;
    session["counter"]=count;
    //remove response.redirect("same page");
 }
```

Your buuton is server side so your page will postback so you do not need to use response.redirect("same page");

Comment: A redirect is not a postback, but a new request.

Comment: You r right. Then @VivekMishra remove 'response.redirect("same page");' as the button is serverside and it will postback.

Comment: In some scenarios that redirect is useful: then a refresh will not re-issue that serverside action. So "remove redirect" might not be an option.

Comment: You are right again :). So let the @VivekMishra if this is the answer to the problem.

Comment: yupp. thank you every one for your kind help and useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed redirecting, and not posting back, just check, on page load, if your initial variable has been set? If not, set it. If it is set, ignore setting it.

```
'set initial value

if session("counter") is nothing then
 session("counter") = 0
end if
```

If you are posting back, you could also use the above, or you could:

```
If not isPostBack then
 session("counter") = 0
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move that initialisation to a different page. Instead of directly jumping to your "same page" from another part of your application, julp to an "initializer" instead. *That* page initializes your session variables and immediately redirects to your "same page".

Your "Button_Click" still redirects to "same page", bypassing that initialisation.